# Listbox should only display pdf extentions?

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have a listbox which reads all files within a predefined directory. in this directory are all sorts of files. What i would like  is to "filter" for PDF files only, so that only files with the.pdf extention are displayed in the listbox

How do i do this?

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' make a reference to a directory
    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\")
    Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    Dim dra As IO.FileInfo

    'list the names of all files in the specified directory
    For Each dra In diar1
        ListBox1.Items.Add(dra)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
For Each dra In diar1
    If System.IO.Path.GetExtension(dra.Name).ToLower() = "pdf" Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(dra)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

[DirectoryInfo.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx) has an overload that takes a string.
This string is the pattern to filter the file list result.

So your code could be simplified (and of course, having less files to loop over, it will be more performant) using

```
Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\")
Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.pdf")
Dim dra As IO.FileInfo
For Each dra In diar1
    ListBox1.Items.Add(dra)
Next
```

Also, be aware, that if you don't need the file FileInfo objects you could simply use

```
Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(yourDirectory, "*.PDF")
```

[Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) returns just a string array with the names requested